# replace comma with dot on fly

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, input

I am trying to replace "comma" with a "dot" in input type "Text". Currently in my code I am restricting my pattern `"^([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]*$"` but I would like to allow user to type "comma" (`,`) but replace automatically with "period" (`.`)

```
<input
  type="text"
  ref="double"
  pattern="^([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]*$"
  onKeyUp={this.validateKeyEvents.bind(this)}
  value={this.state.value}
  onChange={this.inputChanged.bind(this)}
/>



validateKeyEvents(event){
    console.log("event occured" + event.charCode);
    var keyVal = event.charCode;
    if(keyVal == 188)
    {
      console.log("comma");
      event.preventDefault();
      var UserInput = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.double).value;
      UserInput = UserInput.replace(/,/g, ".");
      return true;
    }
    else if(keyVal == 8 || keyVal == 46)
      return true;
    else if(keyVal == 0)
      return true;
    else if (keyVal == 9 || keyVal == 13 || keyVal == 110 || keyVal == 190)
      return true;
    else if(keyVal >=48 || keyVal <= 57)
      return true;
    else if(keyVal >= 96 || keyVal <= 105)
      return true;
    else if(keyVal >=35 || keyVal <=40)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }



inputChanged(event) {
    var value = event.target.validity.valid
      ? event.target.value
      : this.state.value;
    this.setState(
      {
        value: value
      });
  }
```

Comment: Since you are using React, why not handle it where you go `setState`?

Comment: you mean while setting the state of value replace comma with period and display it?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I mean.

Comment: ok i gave a try but its failing. can you provide some hints how to handle? currently it working in following way. 1. user can enter 1.01 for example 2. user cannot enter multiple "period". My current issue is: when user enters "comma" i would like to handle in such a way that it accepts "comma" but convert it to "period" on fly .. example when user enters 1,02 it should display 1.02

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply pass the replaced string as a value for the `input` :

```js
<input 
  value={this.state.value.replace('.', ',')} 
  onChange={e => this.setState({value: e.target.value})} ... />
```

And just change your pattern to use a comma instead of a dot.

```
pattern="^([0-9]*[,])?[0-9]*$"
```

Answer (score 0):

So i did the following changes:

in validateKeyEvents i added

```
if(keyVal == 188)
{
  return true;
}
```

and in input

```
              <input
                type="text"
                pattern="^([0-9]*[.?,])?[0-9]*$"
                onKeyUp={this.validateKeyEvents.bind(this)}
                value={this.state.value.replace(',','.')}
              />
```